# Is possible to cherry-pick variables when using "-Wall" flag on gcc compiler to avoid "false" positive warnings by [-Wunused-variable]?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I declared two variables as:

```
char vowels[5] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
char nStrings[2][4] = { {'a', 'c', 'p', 'x'}, {'b', 'd', 'q', 'y'} };
```

And used them to make comparisons with `ìf` statements, so, from my perspective they are being used. The initial values are not overwritten, no changes.

When compiling the code using `-Wall` flag some warnings about `[-Wunused-variable]` are triggered

```bash
gcc -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:26:10: warning: unused variable ‘nStrings’ [-Wunused-variable]
   26 |     char nStrings[2][4] = { {'a', 'c', 'p', 'x'}, {'b', 'd', 'q', 'y'} };
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:25:10: warning: unused variable ‘vowels’ [-Wunused-variable]
   25 |     char vowels[5] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
      |          ^~~~~~
gcc -g -Wall main.o -o main
```

**Is there an alternative to prevent these "false" positive triggers while still looking for unused variables?**

I tried declaring them using `const` like

```
const char nStrings[2][4] = { {'a', 'c', 'p', 'x'}, {'b', 'd', 'q', 'y'} };
```

but that just triggered yet another warning

```
warning: ‘nStrings’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
```

and the other warning remains.

I know about the `[-Wno-unused-variable]` flag exists but using it will miss variables that genuinely are not being used at all.

The only option is ignore it?

[Here is the complete code](https://gitlab.com/hasecilu/AoC/-/blob/main/2015/05/main.c)

**EDIT**: I realized that I was using `#define PART 2` instead of `#define PART 1` and therefore the variable was effectively not being used. Sorry for wasting your time T_T, is there a harakiri button?

Comment: Based on the information in the post: Not reproduced. [See here.](https://godbolt.org/z/eWz39bfEz)

Comment: If you comment out those two variables, do you get an error?  If not, it's not a false positive.

Comment: Move the definitions inside of the `#if` block where they're used.

Comment: Hi, I have added a link to the complete code.
I also checked `godbolt` and get the same warnings.

Comment: If I comment those variables there is an error cause the variables are readed.
main.c:34:36: error: ‘vowels’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘vows’?

Comment: You're getting the error because of `vowels[0] = 'a';`, so you would have to comment that out as well. But assignment to a variable that's never read doesn't change its "unused" status.

Comment: Ok, now I have realized that due to directive `#define PART        2` instead of value 1 "that" code was not being compiled being the warnings correct. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You can delete your question if you (correctly, probably) think it is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You may use GCC's *unused* attribute:

> unused — This attribute, attached to a variable or structure field,
> means that the variable or field is meant to be possibly unused. GCC
> does not produce a warning for this variable or field.

```
/* AFAIK, both GCC and Clang supports this. */
__attribute__((unused))
```

There's an alternative, if your compiler supports it:

```
/* You can use the __has_c_attribute macro to check if it does.
*
* #ifdef __has_c_attribute
* #if __has_c_attribute(maybe_unused)
*
* Do something mysterious macro-trickery here. 
*
* I define a macro MAYBE_UNUSED that expands to one of the following;
* 1) [[maybe_unused]] if __has_c_attribute(maybe_unused)
*    evaluates to true.
* 2) __attribute__((unused)) if __GNUC__ or __clang__ 
     evaluates to true.
* 3) Nothing.
*/
[[maybe_unused]] /* C2X*/
```